# Haskell: type variables and generic types

Tags: function, haskell, types, transparency, referential

When I mention in the type signature of the function `isQuestion` the types explicitly, GHCi compiles it perfectly:

```
isQuestion :: [Char] -> Maybe Bool
isQuestion [] = Nothing
isQuestion xs = Just (last xs == '?')
```

However, when I turn to 'generic' code, it doesn't work:

```
isQuestion :: [a] -> Maybe b
isQuestion [] = Nothing
isQuestion xs = Just (last xs == '?')
```

since I get the below error:

```
<interactive>:138:17: error:
    * Couldn't match type `b' with `Bool'
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          isQuestion :: forall a b. [a] -> Maybe b
        at <interactive>:136:1-28
      Expected type: Maybe b
        Actual type: Maybe Bool
    * In the expression: Just (last xs == '?')
      In an equation for `isQuestion':
          isQuestion xs = Just (last xs == '?')
    * Relevant bindings include
        isQuestion :: [a] -> Maybe b (bound at <interactive>:137:1)
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think it's because the expression can only ever evaluate to `Maybe Bool` in the second example, it's either `Nothing` or `Just Bool`.

Comment: `[a] -> Maybe b` means it should work **for all** `a` and `b`. Walk through what would happen if the compiler let you call `isQuestion` with an argument of, say, `[4]`. Ultimately it would end up trying to evaluate the expression `4 == '?'`, which doesn't make sense since you can't compare values of different types.

Comment: When you write a generic function, the *caller* specifies the concrete types. So if you write a function of type `a -> a`, for example, it must work for `Int -> Int`, `Char -> Char`, `String -> String`, or any other concrete type in place of `a`. That means you can’t assume anything about the operations available on `a` or what type it is, without additional constraints—for example, `Eq a` to enable using `==` and `/=`. Your function assumes `a` is `Char` and `b` is `Bool`—it’s not as generic as the type signature says. (Other answers here explain how to fix this, depending on what you want.)

Comment: AFAIK, the only possible implementation of `f :: [a] -> Maybe b` is `f _ = Nothing`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First observation is that

```
last xs == something
```

can only work if there is a definition of `(==)` in scope for the elements of `xs`. But as the compiler knows nothing about `a`, there is no such thing. You must narrow `a` to be the subset of types with equality:

```
isQuestion :: Eq a => [a] -> Maybe b
```

The second observation is that `something` is a `Char` in your code (`'?'`), so this method can only ever work when `a ≡ Char`. Instead, you could add that something as a parameter:

```
isQuestion :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe b
```

Finally, as has been pointed out, you have a concrete return type, i.e. `Maybe Bool`, as

```
(==) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

So your function's signature could be

```
isQuestion :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Bool
```

**Edited this paragraph for clarity** Note that, depending on your business logic, you might not want to make a special case of the empty string. If the only thing you care about is whether a string ends with a question mark, then `Nothing` and `Just false` would virtually mean the same thing. In that case, your function becomes a "yes or no" question and you can drop the `Maybe`:

```
isQuestion :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
isQuestion x = isSuffixOf [x]
```

or simply

```
isQuestion :: String -> Bool
isQuestion = isSuffixOf "?"
```

Comment: Thanks Regis. But when you say "thus `Maybe Bool` would be redundant", what do you exactly mean?

Comment: oh, sorry that was not very clear. I'll update. I meant that, if my assumption applies, then `Nothing` and `Just false` would mean virtually the same thing, and so you could get away with just a `Bool`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I have put the `Maybe` type in the first place to consider the case of error (an empty list)..

Answer (score 4):

The type `[a] -> Maybe b` is shorthand for `forall a b. [a] -> Maybe b`. But `isQuestion` doesn't work *for all* types `a` and `b`, it only works specifically if `a` is `Char` and `b` is `Bool`.

Comment: I think you mean if a is `Char` not `[Char]`

Answer (score 2):

Parametric polymorphism is *not* subtyping or supertyping. It's a statement that the implementation of a value doesn't depend on part of the type. In fact, the implementation works for any choice of type at all.

Your implementation doesn't work for any choice of type.  It only works if `a` is `Char` and `b` is `Bool`. You can tell this because it uses `(== '?')` in there, which is a function of type `Char -> Bool`.

Comment: Doesn't parametric polymorphism give rise to [a subtyping relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley–Milner_type_system#Polymorphic_type_order) (you get an order on types and you upcast by specializing), though? There's *more* to it, but you can still use subtyping to explain why this can't work. Specifically, here we need `forall a b. [a] -> Maybe b`, but we've a value for a supertype, `[Char] -> Maybe Bool`, so we can't use it. If we had an `exists` quantifier, we'd even get a nice hierarchy with `exists a. a` at the top, everything else in between, and `forall a. a` at the bottom.

Comment: Sure.  Some polymorphic types are more general than others. But without existentials, it doesn't work at all like one would expect with OO-style subtyping. Unless you've got an incredibly strong type theory background, it's better to just learn how parametric polymorphism works first, and then place it in the theory terms later.